# jQuery, javascript - How add decimal numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, decimal

I have created function after button click:

```
var cena_poczatkowa = parseFloat($("#cena_aktualna").text());
    var cena_dodana = cena_poczatkowa + 1.01;
    $("span#cena_aktualna").text(cena_dodana);
```

And span in html:

```
<span id="cena_aktualna">0.00</span>
```

Everything working fine, after every click number is changed in span: 1.01, 1.02.
But after thrid click I see 3.0300000000000002.
After fourth click I see again properly 4.04.
Why after third click I see this strange number?

Here is my working script so you can see this bug: http://jsfiddle.net/H3pfH/

Comment: Possible duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since floating point math is inherently imprecise, try using [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to round it to a suitable number of digits:

`var cena_dodana = (cena_poczatkowa + 1.01).toFixed(4);`

http://jsfiddle.net/H3pfH/1/

Comment: +1 for using `toFixed()`, but I'd suggest fixing it when there is the need to display the result, and not when calculating the number data, like so: ` $("span#cena_aktualna").text(cena_dodana.toFixed(2));`

Comment: Good point. It all depends on what said number is being used for elsewhere in the code. In this case, I would prefer to round it immediately since it corrects an error and makes the result *more* correct. If I were taking square roots or some other computation that I would expect to produce a long decimal value, I would round it at the end.